# Why firefox can't get elements node as well as IE?

Tags: javascript, firefox, getelementbyid

This is a script for selecting a method for pay. It works in IE but when I run it in FF it stops with this error:
`Error: document.getElementById("tdeposit").childNodes[0].childNodes[0] is undefined.`

You can paste this code to a html file and see the problem:

I have removed some website addresses because of privacy issues , the image links changed

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<style>
#tdeposit {
width:550px;
margin:10px auto;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:13px;
font-weight:bold;
letter-spacing:1px;
color:#444;
text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<script>
function methodis(method){
if(method=='wm'){
document.getElementById('tdeposit').childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].style.visibility='visible';
document.getElementById('tdeposit').childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[2].style.visibility='visible';
document.getElementById('tdeposit').childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[3].style.visibility='visible';
document.getElementById('tdeposit').childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[4].style.visibility='visible';
document.getElementById('tdeposit').childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('tdeposit').childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[2].style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('tdeposit').childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('tdeposit').childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[4].style.visibility='hidden';
document.deposit.method[0].checked=true;
}
if(method=='lr'){
document.getElementById('tdeposit').childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('tdeposit').childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[2].style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('tdeposit').childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[3].style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('tdeposit').childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[4].style.visibility='hidden';
document.getElementById('tdeposit').childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].style.visibility='visible';
document.getElementById('tdeposit').childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[2].style.visibility='visible';
document.getElementById('tdeposit').childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[3].style.visibility='visible';
document.getElementById('tdeposit').childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[4].style.visibility='visible';
document.deposit.method[1].checked=true;
}
return 0;
}

function calculate(ob,per){
    if(ob.value.length<8){
document.getElementById(ob.name).innerHTML = '$ '+(per*ob.value).toFixed(2);
    }else{
document.getElementById(ob.name).innerHTML = '$ 0';
    }
}
</script>
<form name='deposit' action='deposit.php'>
  <table id='tdeposit' >
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='radio' name='method' value='wm' style='width:20px; height:50px' />
          <img src='http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/images/webmoney.png' onclick='methodis("wm");' /></td>
        <td style='width:110px; visibility: hidden;'> $
          <input style='margin:5px; height:20px; width:50px; text-align:center' type='text' name='wmht' onkeyup='calculate(this,0.98);' />
          WM</td>
        <td style='width:25px; visibility: hidden;'><img src='http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/images/convert.gif' /></td>
        <td style='width:100px; visibility: hidden;' ><span id='wmht' style='color:#060'>$ 0.0</span> HT</td>
        <td style='width:100px; visibility: hidden;'><input type='submit' value=' Deposit ' />
      </tr>
      <tr style='border-top:solid 1px #999'>
        <td><input type='radio' name='method' value='lr' style='width:20px; height:50px' />
          <img src='http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/images/libertyreserve.png' onclick='methodis("lr");'/></td>
        <td style='visibility: hidden;'> $
          <input style='margin:5px; height:20px; width:50px; text-align:center' type='text' name='lrht' onkeyup='calculate(this,0.95);' />
          LR</td>
        <td style='visibility: hidden;'><img src='http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/images/convert.gif' /></td>
        <td style='visibility: hidden;'><span id='lrht' style='color:#060'>$ 0.0 </span> HT</td>
        <td style='visibility: hidden;'><input type='submit' value=' Deposit ' />
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That codes makes me want to shoot somebody.

Comment: If you see code that is repeated line after line [aka `document.getElementById('tdeposit').childNodes[0].childNodes[0]`], you should try to figure out how to remove it. Same code over and over again is inefficient because the browser has to look up that node time and time again.

Comment: Even disregarding better ways to do this, even a small improvement would be to to do something like `row = document.getElementById('tdeposit').childNodes[0].childNodes[0];` and then use "row" a few times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById('tdeposit').childNodes[0]` references the TextNode for whitespace following the `<table>` tag. Perhaps IE is disregarding it, but not other browsers. Use the [children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.children) getter instead of `childNodes`.

Comment: Alex ,i`m reconsidering. In wich part of code should i make change?

Comment: I mean, instead of setting visibility for a bunch of elements, you could add or remove a single CSS class to/from their parent (e.g., `.hidden { visibility: hidden; }`.